# Вызов функций после определенных событий JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Я в JS не силен от слова совсем, так что можете кидать тухлыми помидорами за вопрос, но за сутки гугления я нашел только то, что нашел.

Передо мной стоит задача написать скрипт, который будет менять id тега input. 
В начале имеем:

```
<input type="text" id="1"/>
```

Когда мы вводим текст и нажимаем за пределы этого инпута, у нас отсылается ajax запрос на сервер и в блоке succses я делаю следующее:

```
var inputQuery = document.getElementById("1");
inputQuery.id = "2";

function2.call();
```

где, соответственно:

```
var function2 = function funcName() {
$('#2').blur( function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '2', 
        data: { 
            d: $('#2').val(),
        },
        success: function (response) {

            var inputQuery = document.getElementById("2");
            inputQuery.id = "3";

            function3.call();
        }
    })
});
};
```

И, соответсвенно, так далее, до тех пор, пока все поля не будут перечислены и не "заменят друг друга". Поля заменяются, id элементов тоже корректно меняется, однако чем дальше я иду, тем больше "каскадных" запросов я получаю. Т.е. на второй итерации я отправляю запросы по 1 и 2 ссылка, на третьей по 1, 2 и 3ей ссылкам. И так далее.

Я понимаю, что это связано с тем, что в каждом ajax запросе я вызываю "следующую функцию", но я не представляю, как это правильно переписать, потому что если я сделаю это отдельными функциями и не буду вызывать это, как подзапросы, а как просто n-ое число функций вида:

```
$(document).ready(function sendQuery() { //... });
```

То у меня сработает это только с первой функцией такого вида, а дальше они просто перестанут вызываться. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно решить данную задачу?

Так же буду благодарен за полезные интенсивы и ссылки по JS для общего развития.

Comment: А сколько у вас таких итераций: с `id === 1` до `id === ...`?

Comment: Всего 5, @РустамГимранов

Comment: То есть запрос по адресу `url: '5',` - финальный?

Comment: Да, @РустамГимранов

Comment: На финальном запросе вы отправляете по 5 ссылкам запросы. Но как, зачем, если у вас только одно значение `d: $('#5').val(),` и получается, что по 4 запросам уходит `undefined`?

Comment: Или вы именно от этого и хотите избавиться?

Comment: Да, @РустамГимранов , Именно от этого я и хочу избавиться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... задача написать скрипт, который будет менять `id` тега `input`.

По вашему описанию, больше похоже на стадийную отправку данных, с такой кнопкой <kbd>Далее >></kbd>.

```html
<input type="text" name="d" value="" />
<input type="button" name="send" value="Далее >>" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // Номер текущей стадии.
  var stage = 1;
  // Конечная стадия.
  var limit = 5;

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="send"]').click(function() {
      // Здесь лучше выполнить проверки на валидность поля.
      // ... code.

      sendQuery(stage, {
          d: $('input[name="d"]').val()
        })
        // В случае успешного выполнения запроса:
        .done(function(response) {
          // а) увеличиваем номер шага.
          stage++;

          // б) меняем подписи у кнопочек.
          if (limit === stage) {
            $('input[name="send"]')
              .val('Завершить');
          } else if (limit < stage) {
            $('input[name="send"]')
              .val('Готово')
              .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
          }
        })
        // В случае возникновения ошибок
        // при выполнения запроса.
        .fail(function(error) {
          //
        })
    });
  });

  // Отправка запроса на сервер.
  function sendQuery(url, data) {
    return $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: data,
      // По умолчанию идет GET.
      // method: 'POST',
      // Отменим кеширование.
      cache: false
    });
  }
</script>
```

---

Вариант с использованием одного поля ввода и отправки AJAX запроса по нажатию клавиши `Enter`:

```html
<input type="text" name="d" value="" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // Номер текущей стадии.
  var stage = 1;

  // Конечная стадия.
  var limit = 5;

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="d"]').on('keydown', function(event) {
      // Если нажатая клавиша не `Enter`,
      // то возвращаем true для продолжения
      // всплытия события.
      if (13 !== event.keyCode) return true;

      // Обработка нажатия клавиши `Enter`.
      // Отменяем стандартное поведение, на тот случай,
      // если поле расположено в форме.
      event.preventDefault();

      var $input = $(this);

      // Здесь лучше выполнить проверки
      // на валидность поля `input`.
      // Если не валидно: return false;
      // ... code.

      // Деактивируем поле, пока не будет выполнен запрос AJAX.
      $input.attr('disabled', true);

      sendQuery(stage, {
          d: $input.val()
        })
        // В случае успешного выполнения запроса:
        .done(function(response) {
          // а) увеличиваем номер шага.
          stage++;

          // б) активируем поле ввода.
          if (stage <= limit) $input.attr('disabled', false);
        })
        // В случае возникновения ошибок
        // при выполнения запроса.
        .fail(function(error) {
          //
        });
    });
  });

  // Отправка запроса на сервер.
  function sendQuery(url, data) {
    return $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: data,
      // По умолчанию идет GET.
      // method: 'POST',
      // Отменим кеширование.
      cache: false
    });
  }
</script>
```

---

**NB** В снипетах AJAX запрос не отправляется, поэтому не щелкайте понапрасну.

Comment: Дело в том, что я хочу как раз сделать это все без кнопки: "далее". Т.е. отделаться только одним полем input type="text". Скорее всего Ваш вариант подходит для этого, сейчас подумаю, как его "модернизировать".

Comment: Поменяйте `$('input[name="send"]').click` на `$('input[name="d"]').blur=`

Comment: Оптимальнее было бы по нажатию клавиши `Enter` вместо `blur` отправлять запрос. Дополнить ответ?

Comment: Спасибо, @РустамГимранов . Я сейчас сам немного попытаюсь поразбираться, если ничего не получится, вернусь пытать Вас :D

Comment: Скрипт отлично работает! Спасибо за идею реализации таких фич, @РустамГимранов. Очень помогли!

Comment: @МишаковАлександр, я все таки добавил вариант, о котором упоминал выше.